# c++ char arrays : a[i] = b[i] fails

Tags: c++, char

I got some troubles trying to copy char to char...

Here's args[] definition :

```
char* args[6];
if (1 == ParseQuery(request, &args[0])) ....

#note : args[ARG_DATE] = "201204090600"
```

Here's d definition :

```
struct date {
  char a[4];
  char m[2];
  char j[2];
  char h[4];
};

date d;
```

This is what I'm trying to do :

```
int TileServe::ParseQuery(FastCGIRequest& request, char** args) {

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  d.a[i] = args[ARG_DATE][i];
  d.h[i] = args[ARG_DATE][i+8];
}
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
  d.m[i] = args[ARG_DATE][i+4];
  d.j[i] = args[ARG_DATE][i+6];
}

strcat(filename, "/");
strcat(filename, d.a);
strcat(filename, "/");
strcat(filename, d.m);
...
printf("%s\n", filename);
```

I get :

```
./data/alpes/201204090600/04090600/090600/0600/alpes_201204090600.nc
```

I'm expecting :

```
./data/alpes/2012/04/09/06/alpes_201204090600.nc
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most C functions expect null-terminated strings.  Your substrings (d.a, d.m, ...) are not null-terminated.  Hence `strcat` is appending everything up until the first null-character it finds in memory after your substrings.

One fix is to lengthen the char arrays by one and place the `'\0'` character at the end of your substrings.

Another fix would be to use `strncat` instead of `strcat` to append a specified number of characters.

Comment: @user1219721: `'\0'` not `"\0"` - but yes that is one solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
strncat(filename, "/", 1);
strncat(filename, d.a, 4);
strncat(filename, "/", 1);
strncat(filename, d.m, 2);
...
```

Also, `NUL`-terminate your strings.